# How to sort list view data which is backed with API Response and containing more then one field in each row

Tags: android, listview

I want to sort data in `ListView`. Which contains `title`,`description` ,`price` at their respective position in each row. I want to implement sort functionality on title  in alphabetical order. All field are stored in different array. After sorting each filed should according title. What to do? Please explain with detail example.

Answer (score 0):

Create one **Bean** Class
Your array

array 1) title[]

array 2) description[]

for example  DataBean

```
public class DataBean
{
    String title,desc;
    DataBean(String title,String desc)
    {
        this.title=title;
        this.desc=desc;
    }

}
```

Use this code to merge data
Create Vector;

ex: Vector vec = new Vector;

```
for(int i=0; i< yourArray.length; i++)
{
    vec.add(title[i],description[i]);
}
```

Now you have **vec** of your date.

Just perform **SORT** on any field.

either **title** or **desc**.

You will get your sorted data.

Comment: its not adding two or element in vector.